# DIsplay attribute of an object in jsp with Struts

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts, struts-1

So I have those classes :

```
public class DeviceDto {
  private long number;
  private long blob;

  //getters setters

}

public class PageDto {
  private DeviceDto pda;
  private DeviceDto tab;
  private String message;

  //getters setters
}
```

In my action I make a pageDto and then set it :

```
request.setAttribute("dto", pageDto);
```

Then in the jsp I have :

```
<bean:write name="dto" property="message" />
<bean:write name="dto" property="pda.id" />
<bean:write name="dto" property="tab.id" />
```

however the `pda.id` and `tab.id` do not display anything.
I also tried `${tab.id}` bit this raise an exception saying that there is no getter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<bean:write>` tag in that way. Instead of `<bean:write>` you can use equivalent JSTL tag `<c:out>`.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:out value="${dto.message}" />
<c:out value="${dto.pda.id}" />
<c:out value="${dto.tab.id}" />
```

Comment: It's just displaying ${dto.tab.id}, I've added jstl 1.1.2 and standard 1.1.2 jars and my 2.3 servlet's web.xml is declared as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Don't use 2.3, at least 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Well @Roman C awnser is good, but I found a way to do it with bean:write so I'm posting it too.

Use bean define to define a proberty of dto as a bean and then bean:write can be used.

```
<bean:define name="dto" property="pda" id="pdadto" />
<bean:write name="pdadto" property="id" />
```

This will write `dto.pda.id`